# find_elements_by_partial_link_text(link_text) Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Got this issue:
I'm trying to find the last link on webpage:

```
    try:
            elems=self.br.find_elements_by_partial_link_text(category)
    except NoSuchElementException:
            print 'The Category Name Was Not Found'.category
            f=open("error.log","aw")
            f.write("Cant find category:%s\n"%category)
            f.close()
    elems[-1].click()
```

Now for exmaple the categories I have:
Books (Dynamic Number)
AudioBooks (Dynamic Number)
RomanceBooks (Dynamic Number)

And I try to find "Books"
I want to get the first one! (Also it needs to be the last on the source so can't choose first from the elements) One thing that will work with my system if I was able to choose partial_link_text starting with books and not ending? Any ideas?
I can't use any other method because It's a really dynamic code and most of the stuff changes...

Comment: Could you please clarify a little - you want to get the last of the elements (based on your `elems[-1]`) but you say you want the first one - the first of the `list` you've made or the first of something else?

Comment: @MarkRowlands I want to get the last element (elems[-1]) but it must be starting with my category variable (Books) so it will choose the one that is starting with category variable and not ending so basally the last one that start with category (Books)

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand a little more now. Sorry, another question first:   So is the problem that you use "Books" as your category but instead of just providing a list of "Books" its also including "AudioBooks" and "RomanceBooks" because of the `_partial_link_text`?

Comment: @MarkRowlands Yes exactly.But also I need the last one from The Books Links matches because there is few links with same category before. I need the last match of Books and it must start with Books or it should not be in the list

Comment: Due to the problems presented by the `_partial_link_text` also returning `elements` from the incorrect categories is it perhaps not the best choice of locator in this instance?

Comment: it's the only option ;(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33995/discussion-between-mark-voidale-and-mark-rowlands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
xpath="//a[starts-with(text(), %s)]" % category
elems = self.br.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
elem = elems[-1]
```

xpath will do the `starts-with` part of work, and `elems[-1]` will do the rest

Comment: it's a checkbox I'm trying to click here is the html code do you think it will work for this? `<input class="l-tcb" type="checkbox" id="ext-gen23">` `<a hidefocus="on" href="#" id="ext-gen16"><span unselectable="on">Books (206)</span></a>`

Comment: also start with is basically category

Comment: no, this example won't work. but you can play with xpath. for example, if each pair of `input` and `a` is contained in some node (like in `div` or anything else) you can just use a bit another xpath, like this: `xpath="//a[starts-with(text(), %s)]/../input" % category`, and you'll get the checkbox you want.